I am using top level statements but I keep getting this error: Top-Level Statements must precede namespace and type declarations
Working through a tutorial on Writing and reading files and following along in the book, but when i try and set up the first few lines of code i get the error: "Top-Level Statements must precede namespace and type declarations."
public record Score(string Name, int Points, int Level);

List<Score> MakeDefaultScores()
{
    return new List<Score>
    {
        new Score("R2-D2", 12420, 15),
        new Score("C-3PO", 8543, 9),
        new Score("GONK", -1, 1)
    };
}

Now the record is on line one but when i add the list below that block of code all the lines from the list are underlined with that compiler error. I have had a few difficulties with the same error a few times since using the new top level statements, I say new only becasue i started learning C# before this feature then took some time off and am now learning again. Im clearly missing somthing but i am following the code in the book to the line.
When i comment out the public record line that solves the error but of course now the List has nothing to refrence i.e  is red. i have checked that i am indeed using top level statements and the langue version is on 12.

All of what you have here needs to be declared inside a class.

Thank you for the help, should have seen that in the other post. many thanks.

@500-InternalServerError: No, just reversing the order works fine - at which point there'd effectively be a local function (MakeDefaultScores) declared within Main, and the record type separately.

If you pay more attention to the error message you are getting:
Top-level statements -> Your Local Function declaration called MakeDefaultScores.
must precede namespace and type declarations -> your Score record.
The correct order would be:
List<Score> MakeDefaultScores()
{
    return new List<Score>
    {
        new Score("R2-D2", 12420, 15),
        new Score("C-3PO", 8543, 9),
        new Score("GONK", -1, 1)
    };
}

public record Score(string Name, int Points, int Level);

